# Mask Navbar-fixed-top links on ajax loader

Tags: jquery, ajax, loader

I am displaying loader image on ajaxstart event at the same time changed the opacity of body. But the opacity of navbar-fixed-top is not changed and as well as the links present on it are clickable.
Need to disable that links on ajaxstart when loader image is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if z-index of your navbar for example is : `10`, you must specified `z-index: 11` for your loader image

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkSnP/)

Comment: I have increased the z-index but still links on the navbar are clickable. It should be clickable while displaying loader.

Comment: @SaileeReddy Should be or not ? you want when loader is shown, links that are in navbar clickable or not ?

Comment: I dont want the links clickable on navbar when loader is displayed.

Comment: I have tried with css you have mentioned, but the only difference in my navbar css is its top is fixed and it is 0px. Hence the links are clickable.

Comment: My navbar css is 
`code`
.navbar {
    background-color: #F00;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1030;
    top: 0px;
     overflow: visible;

}

Comment: I am using bootstrap classes

Comment: z-index of my navbar-fixed-top is 1030 so I was trying for 1031...But after that I have increased to 1040. It works fine.